# Removing a runtime's created TabItem by name

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` in my app. Based on the selected checkboxes, I create a `TabItem` at runtime. When a checkbox is unchecked, that `TabItem` must be removed. Now, my problem is, I need just to remove only that `TabItem`.

I was implementing this, and created every `TabItem` again. But as I said, I lose all the info of all tabs when a checkbox is checked or unchecked:

```
tc_Descuento.TabPages.Clear();
```

I was a reading some posts and tried this:

```
TabPage tb = new TabPage();
tb = tc_Descuento.Controls.Find("Cuota-" + Convert.ToString(cuota.num_cuota));
tc_Descuento.TabPages.Remove(tb);
```

The name of the TabItem is : `"Cuota-" + Convert.ToString(cuota.num_cuota)`

What I tried is to create a `TabItem`, then find it in the `TabControl` by its name. And then remove it from the list of `TabPages` in the `TabControl`.

I´m getting a compilation error. Surely, its because I cannot convert a Control item into a TabPage. But then, how can I get that TabItem control as a TabItem and not a control?

Thanks..

EDIT:

```
tb = Convert.ChangeType(tc_Descuento.Controls.Find("Cuota-" + Convert.ToString(cuota.num_cuota), false).First(), TabItem);
```

I tried this now, I need a way to convert the control to a TabItem.. But this is not compilating either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found my answer!

This is the way to do it:

```
tb = (TabPage)(tc_Descuento.Controls.Find("Cuota-" + Convert.ToString(cuota.num_cuota), false).First());
```

You have to cast the type at the beginning.

Hope this can help somebody out!